# Remote CUPS Printing, Is It Possible?

Tags: linux, unix, printing, solaris

I have a RHEL 6 server, and a Solaris 2.6 server. The RHEL 6 server is able to print to a network printer, which is a Laserjet 4014DN, using CUPS. I want to have the Solaris 2.6 server print to that printer as well, but I want the RHEL 6 server to act as the host. (Basically, install it on the RHEL server and share it to the Solaris server).

I've done this in Windows, but not sure how to do this with Linux to UNIX. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to it from Solaris [via IPP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-7761/gedcr/index.html).